# TestFlight Beta testing issue

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I recently uploaded a build to itunesconnect. After uploading the build, I wanted to distribute the build for testing. So in the builds section, I tried turning on the TestFlight Beta Testing switch, this resulted in a error being displayed. The error description was "You can't test this version because all builds have expired". I have checked the certificates and they have not expired. I am stuck here. Here is the image representing the scenario I am facing. Please help me out with this.[image]

Comment: Have you submitted same build for Apple review?

Comment: @Sunil Targe: No I have not submitted for Apple Review.

Comment: @Sunil Targe: But an earlier submitted build was sent for external testing and it says approved(Inactive)

Comment: @RohanBhale Please edit the title of your Question to be specific and descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a bug in iTunes (these days).